# .net data structure for each row having different columns (other than 2D or multidimensional array)

Tags: .net, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures, datatable

Just wondering if there's been any new development of data structures in .Net for raw JSON data like below where each row can have different columns or number of columns

```
[
    {
        "ID":"666734563",
        "NAME":"John",
        "GENDER":"Male",
        "ADDRESS":"Denver, CO"
    },
    {
        "ID":"666732348",
        "NAME":"Jessica",
        "GENDER":"Female",
        "AGE":"41",
        "CAR":"Ford",
        "ACCIDENTS":"0",
        "LICENSE":"A1277847"
    }
]
```

I know we have 2D, jagged and multidimensional arrays, but I was hoping that I could find a data structure for creating a WebAPI endpoint that allows me to query for values, run validations based on the Keys and add metadata to the cells to mark them as Valid / Invalid etc (similar to Tags in .Net DataTables).

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]<myStructure> value)
{
    // do validations
    // do queries
    // do process data etc ...
}
```

I know I can build custom POCO classes and implement IQueryable, IEnumerable interfaces etc but just putting this question out there as I've been a little disconnected with the latest and greatest in the .Net space for some time and wondering if the work I'm going to do is already done by Microsoft or someone else :)

Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated !

Comment: I don't think implementing `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` would help you here. But what you need is either `List<object>` or `List<CommonBaseType>`. Or perhaps even `List<dynamic>`.

Comment: Why can't each object be a `Dictionary<string, string>`, or perhaps `Dictionary<string, object>`?